# installation Error for Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Facing error during the installation of `joomla` 2.5 setup.

Error during the `joomla` installation:

```
        [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108701 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP   1. {main}()   
        /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/installation/index.php:0
      [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108714 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP   2. JFactory::getApplication() /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/installation/index.php:69
                        [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108721 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP   3. JApplication::getInstance()   
         /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/libraries/joomla/factory.php:102
                        [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108728 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP   4. JInstallation->__construct()   
         /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/libraries/joomla/application/application.php:180
                       [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108735 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP   5. JApplication->__construct()   
         /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/installation/includes/application.php:37
                        [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108741 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP   6. JInstallation->_createSession()   
         /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/libraries/joomla/application/application.php:145
                        [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108747 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP   7. JFactory::getSession()   
         /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/installation/includes/application.php:273
                       [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108753 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP   8. JFactory::createSession()   
        /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/libraries/joomla/factory.php:152
                       [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108760 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP   9. JSession::getInstance()   
        /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/libraries/joomla/factory.php:656
                       [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108766 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP  10. JSession->__construct()   
        /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/libraries/joomla/session/session.php:151
                        [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108771 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP  11. JSession->_start()   
        /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/libraries/joomla/session/session.php:114
                        [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108777 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP  12. JRequest::getVar()   
        /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/libraries/joomla/session/session.php:522
                        [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108783 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP  13. JRequest::_cleanVar()   
        /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php:150
                        [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108789 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP  14. JFilterInput->clean()   
        /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php:632
                        [Fri Nov 24 13:27:57.108794 2017] [:error] [pid 8360] [client ::1:52662] PHP  15. JFilterInput->_decode()   
        /var/www/html/Joomla_2.5/libraries/joomla/filter/input.php:251
```

Software used:

```
    pache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
    Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $
    PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
    PHP version: 5.6.32-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
    phpmyadmin
    Version information: 4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2
```

Comment: @kgangadhar . thanks for votes down . i try alot for  formatting  the data . but failed , now can you help me how can i format the data  also i have used the cntrl +K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it my self:

It was the issue of php 5.6 package some of the packages are missing, like curl and xml.

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer, but I'd really encourage you to update everything because you are running old php and old Joomla with the security risks that entails.

Comment: @Elin  thanks for your comment,i was a old running project  so that  why i want to install old php and old joomla